# nVidia Driver - Laptop is forced as one of my monitors

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, display, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get my nVidia Driver to correctly configure my multi-monitor setup.  I have my laptop in a docking station and two monitors hooked up to it.

I had an old driver that this worked correctly with.  However, that driver was causing a lot of "Deferred Procedure Calls" so I upgraded to a newer driver.  But now I am forced to use my Laptop monitor as one of my monitors.

Here is the image in the nVida Control Panel:

[image]

As you can see, both monitors are recognized, but the only options available are to use one of them with the Laptop Display.

Any Ideas?

---

I am running Windows XP (latest updates), I have an nVidia Quadro 1500M.  I have tried several different driver versions and all the new ones have this issue.

Comment: Try a cold boot with the laptop lid closed (if possible). You'll need an external power switch such as on a docking station, I guess. This enabled me to force the dual external monitor solution I needed with nVidia drivers on a Linux laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a function or hot key to alternate which monitors desplay try turning off the laptop monitor with that first, then try to select the two external ones.

I would also try using the windows display properties instead of the nvidia one.

Comment: I have tried both of these to no avail :(